# Shell script to -9 kill based on name

Tags: bash, process, kill

Is there a way (perhaps a script) how to automate this process:

```
petr@sova:~$ ps -ef | grep middleman
petr     18445  2312  1 12:06 pts/2    00:00:01 /home/petr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/middleman                                                                  
petr     18581 13621  0 12:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto middleman
petr@sova:~$ kill -9 18445
```

Unfortunately, `pkill` is too weak as I have to go with `-9` option on `kill`.

Comment: You can use `-9` with `pkill` too...

Comment: In my opinion, it's more elegant and proper to use `-KILL` than `-9`. What number corresponds to what signal is implementation-dependent. `SIGKILL` happens to be `9` on Linux i386 and Linux amd64, but not necessarily everywhere. ([More info here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_-9#Unix_and_Unix-like))

Comment: @EliahKagan: while I like to use `-KILL` too (because it makes code more readable), it should be noted that `SIGKILL = 9` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html), so `-9` is pretty portable nowadays (and does not depend on kernels or architectures).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use your shell to do this task for you:

```
kill -9 $(pidof middleman)
```

The shell executes the command `pidof middleman` first. The output of [pidof(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) is the process id. So the shell substitutes the `pidof`-command with the process id and executes `kill -9 18845` (or whatever the correct process id is).

Comment: What's the difference between this and `kill -9 $(pgrep middleman)`?

Answer (score 58):

There is an even simpler solution than the one of qbi: `killall` let's you kill processes by name, and you can specify signals.

```
killall -9 middleman
```

See [`man killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/killall.1.html) for more information and extra options (there are quite a few).

As the name suggests, this does send the signal to *all* processes named `middleman`. But that's not different from other ways (like `pkill`). Furthermore, `pkill -9 middleman` will target processes whose name match but do not equal `middleman`, such as `middleman2`, as well.

Comment: `killall` for the win!

Comment: kill all middlemen? oh dear...

Answer (score 16):

The other answers are entirely correct, but I might as well add a third option so all are documented here. You can also use:

```
pkill -9 middleman
```

See `man pkill` for more information and extra options.

It doesn't really matter which of these methods you use. They will all work. But knowing the options if useful if you want to modify the behaviour in some way, since the corresponding man pages show what other matching options are available.

Comment: Strange, doesn't work here. Nor does `middleman*`

Comment: Ah. Looking more closely, it seems likely that you're wanting to kill a ruby interpreter, rather than a process really called `middleman`. This is where the differences in how exactly `pkill`, `killall`, `pidof` and `grep` match processes really start to matter!

Answer (score 14):

Just for fun, I'd like to add a more manual, old school way

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep middleman | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: I did that at work a few years ago and the admin gave me a look that said "okay, grandad". Can also add a grep -v grep before the awk to make sure it doesn't kill the grep command too.

Comment: @gerhard, thanks for the edit, couldn't find the back ticks on my iPad. grep -v is a good idea...

Comment: The real old school way would be to write `... grep [m]iddleman ...` to avoid killing the `grep` process by accident. That way the grep cannot match itself because of funny quoting.

Answer (score 14):

```
pkill -9 -f middleman
```

The `-f` option makes it match the complete command line, rather than only the process name.

Note that `-9` should be a last resort signal, not something to use routinely.

Comment: thanks! I really like the ability to match the `complete command line`

Comment: complete command line is really cool!

Answer (score 1):

```
killall -9 -ir regex_pattern
```

which is interactive(safe) and matches the partial command name.